# How to use bitmaps as items on ListPreference?

Tags: android, eclipse, bitmap, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I want to have a setting that the player can choose their desired character. How can I use my imported images as the items on my List Preference view?

This is the screenshot of XML:

[image]

```
<ListPreference
    android:key="bitmap"
    android:title="Character"
    android:entries="@array/bitmap"
    android:entryValues="@array/bitmap_resources"
    android:dialogTitle="Select Character" />
```

In my array:

```
<string-array name="bitmap">
    <item>Car</item>
    <item>Ghost</item>
    <item>Human</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="bitmap_resources">
    <item>**???**</item>
    <item>**???**</item>
    <item>**???**</item>
</string-array>
```

In my class:

```
SharedPreferences prefs =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

Drawable bitmap_char =
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hero);

String bitmapStr = 
    prefs.getString("bitmap", "");

    if(bitmapStr.length() > 0) {
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I can vote for any help or suggestions. thanks.

Comment: sorry i just want to update my question since i didn't get any response on other user. The question before was already been deleted. please apologize

Comment: @matiash Unable to open link.

Comment: @AppKart it was a duplicate question posed _by this same user_. He already deleted it. Nevermind.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586242/how-can-i-store-images-using-sharedpreference-in-android

Comment: sir @AppKart the codes on the link is much harder to read because it is already using the gallery. My only objective here is that I will import selected character images through drawable folders and store them in a preference then a settings that will allow the player to pick its desired character